# Turning detached process into asynchronous task

Tags: docker, python-asyncio, dockerpy

Is it possible to turn `docker run` command with `detach=True` into an asynchronous task? I am planning on running a continuous application that reads data from Kafka/RabbitMQ and processes it in docker containers. I can do this in a blocking way one-by-one, but my goal is to speed up a bit and run up to 4 tasks simultaneously. This would be a nice implementation with co-routines a asyncio.Semaphore. However, I am not sure how to turn background process into something I can control or read state. Any ideas?

My current minimal example uses while loop with single container

```
import docker
import json
from time import sleep

client = docker.from_env()

container = client.containers.run("my_container", "my", detach=True)

while True:

    container.reload()
    if not container.attrs['State']['Running']:
        print(container.logs())
        break
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Usually I’d set this up by having my worker(s) be long-running processes that did work as long as there was work to do.  Then I’d start however many of them I wanted in parallel to my application.  I wouldn’t try to launch a new container per request, and I’d try to avoid the dangerous path of accessing the host Docker socket.

Comment: @David Maze for some reason I need fresh start for each message that is why I formulated it this way.